Inequality involving trigamma function $\psi'$
By chance in my ongoing research, I discovered the following inequality,
$$a^2\psi'(ax-1) + b^2\psi'(bx-1)\geq 2\psi'(x-1),$$
where $\psi'$ is the trigamma function $\psi'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\log \Gamma(x)$, $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers satisfying $a + b = 2$, and the range of $x$ is defined to be $\{x>0: ax - 1>0, bx - 1>0\}$.
Numerical results would indicate that the inequality seems correct, but I failed to prove it.

Directions I attempted:
(1) Jensen's inequality as $\psi'$ is convex and positive:
reduces to show that $$2(a^2 + b^2)\psi'\left(\frac{2a^3+2b^3}{a^2+b^2}x - 1\right) \geq \psi'(x-1),$$ which does not hold numerically. It seems that the Jensen's inequality overshoots below the RHS.
(2) Taylor expansion at $x - 1$. There would always be a remainder term (although higher order) that I do not know how to argue. The inequality seems very tight, leaving no room for an unknown remainder term.

I would appreciate any hints and/or any properties of trigamma function that may be helpful.
